# not sure how to fix long.tostring failure

Tags: java, tostring, long-integer

` I am doing a problem and we are supposed to write a program that reads a sequence of positive integers. The first zero terminates the input. For each input, N, the program computes the smallest base B (where B≥2) such that N is palindromic when written in base B. my code is fine for lowest palindromic bases yet when I get to a higher base with a bigger number, the .ToString method doesn't add my longs to the string correctly. It just adds random letters and numbers.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class num5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nums[] = in.nextLine().split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
            if (nums[i].equals("0")) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            System.out.println(bases(nums[i]));
        }

        for (String var : nums) {
            System.out.println(var);
        }
    }

    public static boolean ispalin(String original) {

        String reverse = "";

        int length = original.length();
        for (int k = (length - 1); k >= 0; k--)
            reverse = reverse + original.charAt(k);
        if (original.equals(reverse))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static int bases(String numb) {
        for (int i = 2; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            String basecheck = "";
            basecheck = Long.toString(Long.parseLong(numb), i);
            if (ispalin(basecheck)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Please include the specific inputs and outputs you're having trouble with.

Comment: What does `Long.parseLong(numb)` return? Can you put a break point and inspect it?

Answer (score 1):

To represent a number in a given base *n*, you must have *n* distinct symbols.

The range of possible bases is limited, and certainly does not go up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. The actual limit is given in `Character.MAX_RADIX`, which has the value `36`.  This is what you should be using instead of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

```
public static int bases(String numb) {
    for (int i = 2; i < Character.MAX_RADIX; i++) {
        String basecheck = "";
        basecheck = Long.toString(Long.parseLong(numb), i);
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] nums = scan.nextLine().split("\\s+");

    for (String num : nums) {
        if ("0".equals(num))
            return;

        System.out.println(base(num));
    }
}

public static int base(String num) {
    final BigInteger b = new BigInteger(num);
    final BigInteger max = b.divide(BigInteger.TWO);

    for (int i = 2; BigInteger.valueOf(i).compareTo(max) <= 0; i++)
        if (isPalindrome(b.toString(i)))
            return i;

    return 0;
}

private static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
    for (int i = 0, j = str.length() - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
        if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(j))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```